# How to Add attributes in the idictionary htmlattributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here I need to add `isChecked` value in Dictionary item.

I tried adding directly but I am getting following error:

```
 " CS1501: No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments"*. Is there any alternate way to add ischecked in Idictionary.
```

My code is:

```
 @{
     bool val = false;
     var isChecked = (val == true) ? new { @Checked = "checked" }  : null;
  }
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "Male",new Dictionary<string,object>{{"id","GenderRdoButton"},{isChecked}})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you even want to use a RadioButton for a bool property in your model? You should use a Checkbox. What is "male"? Radio Buttons are for choosing one option from a group of options.

Comment: Any of these end up working @Vignesh? I'm in the same boat, passing `Dictionary<string, object>` for the `attributes` param keeps leading to a "Parameter count mismatch" error

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me ,

```
@{
                    bool vals = false;
                    var dictionaryObj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    dictionaryObj.Add("id", "goodId");
                    dictionaryObj.Add("class", "sadd");
                    if(vals){
                        dictionaryObj.Add("checked", "checked");   
                    }
                }
                 @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "Good",dictionaryObj) Good
```

Comment: What about for other Html helpers which have `object attributes = null` i.e. the param is an object, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to passing the `val` value to the method like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.valid, val, new { @id = "GenderRdoButton" })
```

Comment: Along with that id i need an another attribute "checked" and that checked attribute should be used only if the model returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload that takes an IDictionary:

```
    @{
        bool val = true;
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"id", "GenderRdoButton"}};
        if (val)
            attributes.Add("checked","checked");
    }
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.valid, "male", attributes) Male
```

Comment: The Output HTMl is like this                                              <input type="radio" value="Male" name="Status" id="Status" values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.String]" keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.String]" count="2" comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]">

Comment: Try using new Dictionary<string,object>